# launch_background.xml color to hex color

Tags: xml, flutter-layout, splash-screen, launch-screen, android-xml-attribute

I want to make my splash screen using **flutter** framework
all I want to do is to change the splash screen color form white to 003A55 in Hex [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B7uS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash
Step 1: In `pubspec.yaml` add setting

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: any

flutter_native_splash:
  color: 003A55
```

Step 2: run command `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`

[image]

working demo

[image]